# How does Guitar Pro work out fret numbers/strings?

Tags: guitar, software, guitar-pro

If one imports say a C Major scale in Guitar Pro, it auto calculates the fret numbers/strings.

Does anyone know by what logic it does this (since there are many possible ways to play a C major scale on a guitar)?  Why one way and not another?

Comment: We can't really comment on their design decisions unless they've published a reason, but I can definitely see a use for finding out what method is used.

Comment: Let me clarify, I am not concerned specifically with Guitar Pro, many other guitar notation app auto calculate frets. So an answer as to how any of them do it, or any rationale around the logic would be intresting. It seems guitar teachers in general seem to use specific patterns down the neck rather than across.

Comment: @FreddyD are you wondering specifically how software does it (with little information about your intent) or in general about the patterns down the neck, including what a guitar teacher would say?  i imagine a guitar teacher will choose the *position* that is easiest for you to stay in or near, provided neither of you are too worried about voicing.

Comment: I am wondering specifically and technically, from a maths point of view. I am looking at building an app that would include auto frettings. I am having issue working out what, if any, logic exists. It is of course possible no logic exists and its just convention developed over time.

Comment: I suggest you get some midi tracks and import them into Guitar Pro. You may be able to identify a pattern. Also you could investigate transposing some tracks.

Comment: @FreddyD unfortunately, i assume that's where they make their money, with proprietary algorithms that help them separate their software from someone else's.  i do believe there is logic, but maybe it would depend on your intended audience?  if this is for beginners, for example, you might default to chords in the open position since many consider them to be the easiest.  maybe you could make them choose a category, like a style of jazz, and then default to close position voicings or drop 2 or whatever.

Comment: @aeroNotAuto, your comments make a lot of sense. As I do more research it seems an array of very similar logics exist and they are in fact genre specific and difficulty specific. Finale tends to use few strings and many frets which would be harder than Guitar Pro which seems to use many strings with minimum fret movement.

Comment: @FreddyD yea it would be fascinating to port this over to datascience.se or kaggle and build up a data set to analyze.  i wonder if any of them would sue us if we figured their algorithm out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wondering on how to get a suitable/optimal fingering position, there are some existing research that develop such algorithms.

For Guitar fingers position, take a look at the following paper: http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD143X/dkand13/Group7Anders/final/Vladimir.Grozman.Christopher.Norman.report.pdf

The algorithm is graph-based where each node represents few elements such as String Number, Fret Number, Note duration, etc. And it tries to find a solution that will minimize the cost of transition between the notes.

For Piano fingers position, take a look at the following paper:
http://ijcai.org/papers07/Papers/IJCAI07-469.pdf

It is based on a statistical model called Hidden Markov Model.